# How do you split information in one element of a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, element

I'm not sure if I am asking this right, but I am trying to take one element in a list of several elements and split the information.

Take feet and inches for instance:

```
['5-11', '6-7', '6-1']
```

How could I split those 1 of those elements into something like this:

```
"the person is 5 feet 11 inches tall." #example
```

That would be like taking the 5 and the 11 apart from one single element.

Would splitting the element be possible so that I could get the 5 apart from the 11?

My code thus far:

```
def splitter(list1)
    print(list[1])
    return "The guy is {} feet {} inches tall.".format(list[1], list[1]) #I am aware taking the same index of list will give me 5-11 for both {}.
```

Comment: well, `5-11` is `-6` because you're dealing with numbers. If it was `'5-11'` (notice the quotes) you'd just split on `'-'`.

Comment: so would I do something like list1[1].split('-11') so that I would only have 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the elements of the list are indeed strings and not an int subtraction, you just split list item at index `0` on `'-'` and supply that to `format` by simply unpacking:

```
def splitter(list1):
    return "The guy is {} feet {} inches tall.".format(*list1[0].split('-'))
```

Or, to make it a bit more clear what you're doing:

```
def splitter(list1):
    feet, inches = list1[0].split('-')
    return "The guy is {} feet {} inches tall.".format(feet, inches)
```